# How would a second image view to a tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, uitableview, uiimageview

i am implementing an app that has 2 images that i need to display on the same tableviewcell.

however i can NOT subclass tableviewcell what so ever, due to the way the app is set up. so i would like to programmatically create an image view, then add to cell.contentview, but it just comes out wrong. Any Help Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)]; //note this is in the cell coordinate system
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: how would i adjust the cell height, to match the image

Comment: You shouldn't add the imageView directly to the cell's view. You should add it to its contentView, as the contentView knows how to resize itself and its subviews if you enter editing mode, rotate, etc.